# El programa se salta el IF y va directo al ELSE

Tags: python

Estoy practicando las excepciones en python y tengo un problema, las excepciones las capturo bien pero luego el programa no funciona correctamente.

```
#Utilizamos este metedo para importar las funciones del archivo
from Funciones import llegadaCamion,nuevoCamion,procesarEnvios,menu,visualizarCamiones,visualizarEnvios,visualizarCiudades

while True:
    # Mostramos el menu
    menu()
        # solicituamos una opción al usuario
    while True:
            try:
                opcionMenu = (int(input("inserta un numero valor >> ")))
                break
            except ValueError:
                print("El valor introducido no es correcto vuelve a intentarlo")

    if opcionMenu=="1":
        print ("")
        nuevoCamion()                      
    elif opcionMenu=="2":
        print ("")
        llegadaCamion()
    elif opcionMenu=="3":
        print ("")
        procesarEnvios()
    elif opcionMenu=="4":
        print("")
        visualizarEnvios()
    elif opcionMenu=="5":
        print("")
        visualizarCamiones()
    elif opcionMenu=="6":
        print("")
        visualizarCiudades()
    elif opcionMenu=="7":
        print ("")
        break
    else:
        input("No has pulsado ninguna opción correcta...\npulsa una tecla para continuar")
```

El caso es que al introducir bien el dato por ejemplo el 1 no entra en el if se va directo al else, eso sucede en todas las opciones, no entiendo porque no entra a los if.

Comment: Hola David, bienvenido a [es.so]. Por favor, lee el [tour] para aprender el funcionamiento básico del sitio.  Estás haciendo `int` con lo que conviertes la opcion a  numero pero luego la comparas con un string. Un saludo.

Comment: Probablemente porque `opcionMenu` es un entero, y en tus `if` lo comparas con string. intenta `if opcionMenu==1:`

Comment: @Pikoh Deberías ponerlo en forma de respuesta porque esta es la solución.

Comment: @VictorHerasmePerez no estoy muy convencido, creo que esta pregunta debería posiblemente cerrarse como _Parece ser un problema que no se puede reproducir o que contiene errores tipográficos._

Answer (score 4, accepted):

El error probablemente resida en la tipologia de datos que tienes en tu condicion if. Al hacer `opcionMenu == "1"` seguramente estes tratando de comparar un entero con un string de esta manera `Int == String` y por tanto la condición no se cumple.

Utiliza `opcionMenu == 1` para comparar el número como un numero y no como una cadena de texto

Comment: Tienes toda la razón del mundo que fallo mas tonto muchas gracias.